# Export tables from a powerpoint file to an excel file

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I have a powerpoint file with lots of tables. The tables are with same columns. How can I export these tables to one excel file automatically?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow's here to help you solve problems with the code you've already researched and written, not to do the job for you from scratch.

Comment: I can manually copy the tables to excel. Is there a way to do this automatically, e.g. using VBA?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but as I mentioned, this isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub DataTransfer()

Dim shp As Shape, i%, j%

'    Dim colCount As Integer
'    Dim rowCount As Integer


Dim rowNum As Integer
Dim rng As Object

Set rng = GetObject(, "Excel.Application").Range("a1")  ' start at top of  worksheet

    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

    For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes

        If shp.HasTable Then

            With shp.Table
colCount = .Columns.Count
rowCount = .Rows.Count

                For rowNum = 0 To .Rows.Count - 1

                    For j = 0 To 4
                        rng.Offset(rowNum, j).Value = (.Cell(rowNum + 1, j + 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange)
                    Next j

                    rng.Offset(rowNum, 4).Interior.Color = (.Cell(rowNum + 1, 5).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange)

                Next rowNum

                Set rng = rng.Offset(rowNum + 1) 

            End With
        End If
    Next shp
Next i
```